# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.ao.pruning'

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to train my custom dataset using D2Go.

D2Go official Repository Link: https://github.com/facebookresearch/d2go

But I am getting error. I have tried all possible ways to solve it. Still it shows error. Can anyone suggest me to solve it?

Already install below code as told in repository!

```
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/d2go
!python -m pip install ./d2go
```

`from d2go.model_zoo import model_zoo`

```
Google Colab Output:

ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
----> 1 from d2go.model_zoo import model_zoo

5 frames
/content/d2go/d2go/trainer/fsdp.py in
14 from d2go.trainer.helper import parse_precision_from_string
15 from detectron2.utils.registry import Registry
---> 16 from torch.ao.pruning import fqn_to_module
17 from torch.cuda.amp import GradScaler
18 from torch.distributed.fsdp.fully_sharded_data_parallel import (

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.ao.pruning'
```

Answer (score 1):

for D2GO just comment out the error line

```
#16 from torch.ao.pruning import fqn_to_module
```

it will work!

Answer (score 0):

```
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/d2go
!python -m pip install ./d2go

...
your code
...
```

Comment: already installed so many times but gave same errors! :(